# Mapping JPA Entity : annotation oneToMany manyToOne

Tags: jpa, java-ee-6

I have an error in the mapping of my tables.
I do not know how to deal with this error.
Can you help me please?
Thank you very much.

Entity and Relationship : one RefCollectivite ==> many ColPlanCompteM61

Here is my code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "RefCollectivite")
public class RefCollectivite implements Serializable {

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE, mappedBy = "refCollectivite")
private List<ColPlanCompteM61> listePlanCompteM61;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int idPk;

private String libelle;

public RefCollectivite() {
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "ColPlanCompteM61")
public class ColPlanCompteM61 implements Serializable {

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "refCollectiviteFk")
private RefCollectivite refCollectivite;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int idPk;
private int refCollectiviteFk;
```

Error :

```
Infos:   EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 
2.6.1.v20150605-31e8258
Grave:   Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [EclipseLink-0] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.1.v20150605- 
31e8258): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.IntegrityException
Descriptor Exceptions: 
---------------------------------------------------------
Exception [EclipseLink-48] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.1.v20150605- 
31e8258): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: Multiple writable mappings exist for the field 
[ColPlanCompteM61.REFCOLLECTIVITEFK].  Only one may be defined as writable, 
all others must be specified read-only.
Mapping: org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.ManyToOneMapping[refCollectivite]
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(entity.ColPlanCompteM61 --> 
[DatabaseTable(ColPlanCompteM61)])
```

Comment: Remove `private int refCollectiviteFk;`. As the error message says, you're mapping this column twice: once in the ManyToOne, and once by this useless field.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "RefCollectivite")
public class RefCollectivite implements Serializable {

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "refCollectiviteFk")
    private List<ColPlanCompteM61> listePlanCompteM61;



@Entity
@Table(name = "ColPlanCompteM61")
public class ColPlanCompteM61 {

    @JoinColumn(name = "refCollectiviteFk", referencedColumnName = "refCollectiviteFk", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private RefCollectivite refCollectivite;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int idPk;
    private int refCollectiviteFk;
```